# Dynamically add js script tag element in HTML - What happens under the hood?

Tags: javascript

So I stumbled on this the other day, and whether or not it's a good idea it got me wondering how it actually works under the hood.

Say you have the following JavaScript code attached to a click event:

```js
someElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var js = 'function someFunction() {'
              + 'alert(\'It works!\');'
           + '}';

    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag .appendChild(document.createTextNode(js));

    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.appendChild(scriptTag );
});
```

And on another click event you have the following:

```js
someOtherElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    someFunction();
});
```

This dynamically adds a script tag to the html, the javascript is parsed and the function 'someFunction' is accessible and executes.

Now if you remove the script tag from the DOM, the javascript still executes, which is as expected, but if you replace the script tag with a new one containing a new, different version of the 'someFunction' function, only the new version executes.

So what happens to the previous version of the function when it gets overwritten? Does it still exist in memory? Does javascript keep some kind of internal index of named functions with pointers to the latest versions and the others get essentially orphaned?

Answer (score 1):

Stuff usually only hangs around so long as there's a reference to it (though these references aren't always obvious). In your example, you declare a function (in a roundabout way) and, as part of that declaration, assign it to the variable `window.someFunction`. If you were to assign something else to `window.someFunction` after that, the old function would be eventually garbage collected because nothing references it any longer.

Declaring a named function is similar to, but not exactly the same as, declaring an anonymous function and assigning it to variable:

```
window.someFunction = function(){};
```

If you wanted to keep the old function around, you could, of course, assign it to an additional variable, like any other value.